# on implementing a .htaccess file server error comes

Tags: .htaccess

i want to remove  .php extensions from all pages in my localhost website 
  i have this code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond
%{REQUEST_FILENAME}
!-d
RewriteCond
%{REQUEST_FILENAME}
!-f
RewriteRule
^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$$1.php
```

now on running any page i am getting this error
Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
error 500

i am new to mod_rewriting what am i doing wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rewrite your rule like this: `RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]`

Full config may looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: thanx alot brother